JavaFX Application Fails to Load FXML File with IllegalStateException: Location is not set
I am developing a JavaFX application using Maven in IntelliJ IDEA. My application fails to load the FXML file and throws the following exception:
C:\Users\Bruce\.jdks\openjdk-22.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=22421:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\22-ea+11\javafx-controls-22-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\22-ea+11\javafx-graphics-22-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\22-ea+11\javafx-base-22-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\22-ea+11\javafx-fxml-22-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\22-ea+11\javafx-web-22-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\22-ea+11\javafx-media-22-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\22-ea+11\javafx-swing-22-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\22-ea+11\javafx-swing-22-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.7.3\postgresql-42.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.42.0\checker-qual-3.42.0.jar -p C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\controlsfx\controlsfx\11.1.2\controlsfx-11.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\22-ea+11\javafx-media-22-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\22-ea+11\javafx-base-22-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\22-ea+11\javafx-web-22-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-core\12.3.1\ikonli-core-12.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\22-ea+11\javafx-fxml-22-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\net\synedra\validatorfx\0.4.0\validatorfx-0.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\22-ea+11\javafx-graphics-22-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\Desktop\PharmacyManagementSystem_v1.0.1\target\classes;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-javafx\12.3.1\ikonli-javafx-12.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\22-ea+11\javafx-controls-22-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\Bruce\.m2\repository\eu\hansolo\tilesfx\11.48\tilesfx-11.48.jar -m trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystemv/trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystem.PharmacyManagementSystem Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)   at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)   at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)   at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1147) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method   at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)  at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:  /C:/Users/Bruce/Desktop/PharmacyManagementSystem_v1.0.1/target/classes/trojanlabs/pharmacymanagementsystem/hello-view.fxml:84    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2727)    at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2705)  at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2568)  at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2536)  at trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystemv/trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystem.PharmacyManagementSystem.start(PharmacyManagementSystem.java:13)    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)     at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)     at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)  at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)   at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)    at javafx.graphics@22-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)  ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce 10 to class javafx.geometry.Insets.  at javafx.fxml@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:497)   at javafx.fxml@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:259)  at javafx.fxml@22-ea/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:54)   at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.applyProperty(FXMLLoader.java:525)  at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:375)   at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:337)   at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:248)  at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:780)     at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2974)     at javafx.fxml@22-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2659)  ... 12 more Exception running application trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystem.PharmacyManagementSystem  Process finished with exit code 1     

Here's  my PharmacyManagementSystem class:
package trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystem;

//import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PharmacyManagementSystem extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(PharmacyManagementSystem.class.getResource("/trojanlabs/pharmacymanagementsystem/hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pharmacy Management System");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Here's my PharmacyController class:
package trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystem;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class PharmacyController {
    private final PharmacyService pharmacyService;

    // Drug fields
    @FXML
    private TextField drugCodeField;
    @FXML
    private TextField drugNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField drugPriceField;
    @FXML
    private TextField supplierCodeFieldForDrug; // Changed variable name to avoid conflict
    @FXML
    private TextField drugStockField;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Drug> drugTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Drug, String> drugCodeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Drug, String> drugNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Drug, Double> drugPriceColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Drug, String> drugSupplierColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Drug, Integer> drugStockColumn;

    // Supplier fields
    @FXML
    private TextField supplierCodeField;
    @FXML
    private TextField supplierNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField supplierLocationField;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Supplier> supplierTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Supplier, String> supplierCodeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Supplier, String> supplierNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Supplier, String> supplierLocationColumn;

    // Customer fields
    @FXML
    private TextField customerIdField;
    @FXML
    private TextField customerNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField customerContactField;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Customer> customerTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> customerIdColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> customerNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> customerContactColumn;

    // Sale fields
    @FXML
    private TableView<Sale> saleTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sale, Integer> saleIdColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sale, String> saleDrugColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sale, Integer> saleQuantityColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sale, String> saleBuyerColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sale, Date> saleDateColumn;

    public PharmacyController() {
        pharmacyService = new PharmacyService();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        drugCodeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("code"));
        drugNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        drugPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        drugSupplierColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().supplierProperty().get().nameProperty());
        drugStockColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stock"));
        loadDrugData();

        supplierCodeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("code"));
        supplierNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        supplierLocationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("location"));
        loadSupplierData();

        customerIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        customerNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        customerContactColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("contact"));
        loadCustomerData();

        saleIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        saleDrugColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().drugProperty().get().nameProperty());
        saleQuantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
        saleBuyerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("buyer"));
        saleDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
        loadSaleData();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleAddDrug() {
        String drugCode = drugCodeField.getText();
        String name = drugNameField.getText();
        double price = Double.parseDouble(drugPriceField.getText());
        String supplierCode = supplierCodeFieldForDrug.getText();
        int stock = Integer.parseInt(drugStockField.getText());

        Supplier supplier = pharmacyService.searchSupplier(supplierCode);
        if (supplier != null) {
            Drug drug = new Drug(drugCode, name, price, supplier, stock);
            pharmacyService.addDrug(drug);
            loadDrugData();
        } else {
            // Handle supplier not found
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Supplier Not Found");
            alert.setContentText("Supplier with code " + supplierCode + " does not exist.");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleAddSupplier() {
        String supplierCode = supplierCodeField.getText();
        String name = supplierNameField.getText();
        String location = supplierLocationField.getText();

        Supplier supplier = new Supplier(supplierCode, name, location);
        pharmacyService.addSupplier(supplier);
        loadSupplierData();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleAddCustomer() {
        String customerId = customerIdField.getText();
        String name = customerNameField.getText();
        String contact = customerContactField.getText();

        Customer customer = new Customer(customerId, name, contact);
        pharmacyService.addCustomer(customer);
        loadCustomerData();
    }

    private void loadDrugData() {
        List<Drug> drugs = pharmacyService.viewAllDrugs();
        drugTable.getItems().setAll(drugs);
    }

    private void loadSupplierData() {
        List<Supplier> suppliers = pharmacyService.viewAllSuppliers();
        supplierTable.getItems().setAll(suppliers);
    }

    private void loadCustomerData() {
        List<Customer> customers = pharmacyService.viewAllCustomers();
        customerTable.getItems().setAll(customers);
    }

    private void loadSaleData() {
        List<Sale> sales = pharmacyService.viewAllSales();
        saleTable.getItems().setAll(sales);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleGenerateReport() {
        pharmacyService.generateReport();
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Report");
        alert.setHeaderText("Report Generated");
        alert.setContentText("Report has been generated successfully.");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}

And here's my hello-view.fxml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="trojanlabs.pharmacymanagementsystem.PharmacyController" spacing="10" padding="10">
    <Label text="Pharmacy Management System" style="-fx-font-size: 16px; -fx-font-weight: bold;"/>

    <!-- Drugs Management -->
    <Label text="Drugs Management" style="-fx-font-size: 14px; -fx-font-weight: bold;"/>
    <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <Label text="Drug Code:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="drugCodeField"/>
        <Label text="Name:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="drugNameField"/>
        <Label text="Price:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="drugPriceField"/>
        <Label text="Supplier Code:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="supplierCodeField"/>
        <Label text="Stock:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="drugStockField"/>
        <Button text="Add Drug" onAction="#handleAddDrug"/>
    </GridPane>
    <TableView fx:id="drugTable">
        <TableColumn text="Code" fx:id="drugCodeColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Name" fx:id="drugNameColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Price" fx:id="drugPriceColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Supplier" fx:id="drugSupplierColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Stock" fx:id="drugStockColumn"/>
    </TableView>

    <!-- Suppliers Management -->
    <Label text="Suppliers Management" style="-fx-font-size: 14px; -fx-font-weight: bold;"/>
    <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <Label text="Supplier Code:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="supplierCodeFieldForDrug"/>
        <Label text="Name:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="supplierNameField"/>
        <Label text="Location:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="supplierLocationField"/>
        <Button text="Add Supplier" onAction="#handleAddSupplier"/>
    </GridPane>
    <TableView fx:id="supplierTable">
        <TableColumn text="Code" fx:id="supplierCodeColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Name" fx:id="supplierNameColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Location" fx:id="supplierLocationColumn"/>
    </TableView>

    <!-- Customers Management -->
    <Label text="Customers Management" style="-fx-font-size: 14px; -fx-font-weight: bold;"/>
    <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <Label text="Customer ID:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="customerIdField"/>
        <Label text="Name:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="customerNameField"/>
        <Label text="Contact:"/>
        <TextField fx:id="customerContactField"/>
        <Button text="Add Customer" onAction="#handleAddCustomer"/>
    </GridPane>
    <TableView fx:id="customerTable">
        <TableColumn text="ID" fx:id="customerIdColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Name" fx:id="customerNameColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Contact" fx:id="customerContactColumn"/>
    </TableView>

    <!-- Sales Management -->
    <Label text="Sales Management" style="-fx-font-size: 14px; -fx-font-weight: bold;"/>
    <TableView fx:id="saleTable">
        <TableColumn text="ID" fx:id="saleIdColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Drug" fx:id="saleDrugColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Quantity" fx:id="saleQuantityColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Buyer" fx:id="saleBuyerColumn"/>
        <TableColumn text="Date" fx:id="saleDateColumn"/>
    </TableView>

    <!-- Report Generation -->
    <Button text="Generate Report" onAction="#handleGenerateReport"/>
</VBox>

I have verified the file paths and class names, but the issue persists. What might be causing the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set error, and how can I fix it?

Check out How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application? and Where to put resource files in JavaFX

Note at least the first link provides some debugging techniques to help determine what is going wrong. One thing to make sure is that (1) the resources are under src/main/resources and (2) Maven is copying the resources to the target directory. Also, when running your project in a development environment, I recommend you use Maven to execute the project, not the IDE (though the IDE can be configured to delegate to Maven).
